# How do I generate random number between 0 and 1 in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, random

I want to get the random number between 1 and 0. However, I'm getting 0 every single time. Can someone explain me the reason why I and getting 0 all the time? 
This is the code I have tried.

```
Random random = new Random();
int test = random.Next(0, 1);
Console.WriteLine(test);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: There is only one integer number, which is `>= 0` and `< 1`. Thus, you are getting what you are asking.

Comment: Please read the documentation for `Random.Next` and look the values you're giving. If you wanted a non-integer, you're using the wrong call. If you wanted to get 0 or 1, you should be passing 2 as the exclusive upped bound.

Comment: double test =random.NextDouble();

Answer (score 45, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4), `Next` returns an integer random number between the (inclusive) minimum and the (exclusive) maximum:

> **Return Value**
>
> A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to minValue and less than maxValue; that is, the range of return values includes minValue but not maxValue. If minValue equals maxValue, minValue is returned.

The only integer number which fulfills

```
0 <= x < 1
```

is `0`, hence you always get the value `0`. In other words, `0` is the only integer that is within the half-closed interval `[0, 1)`.

So, if you are actually interested in the integer values `0` or `1`, then use `2` as upper bound:

```
var n = random.Next(0, 2);
```

If instead you want to get a decimal between 0 and 1, try:

```
var n = random.NextDouble();
```

Answer (score 12):

Ok, I suspect that you want to generate a random [Unit Interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_interval#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20unit%20interval,I%20(capital%20letter%20I).). This is used in math, stats, logic, and physics all over the place, so it seems like a pretty logical request.

Now if that is what you want, every single answer on this page regarding doubles is wrong. Which is sort of hilarious, because everyone is quoting the documentation. If you generate a double using NextDouble(), you will not get a number between 0 and 1 *inclusive* of 1, you will get a number from 0 to 1 *exclusive* of 1. That's no good if you want a unit interval. (Perhaps you are just trying to flip a coin, your question is a little vague....)

**MUCH LATER ADDENDUM**

I go off on a long tangent about *why* getting a random inclusive float in the range of {0,1} is really hard to do. Skip to the bottom for a clever hack that will do the trick if you are just trying to solve this problem and get on with life.

**BACK TO THE RANT**

To get a double, you would have to do some trickery like this:

```
public double NextRandomRange(double minimum, double maximum)
{
     Random rand = new Random();
     return rand.NextDouble() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum;
}
```

and then call

```
NextRandomRange(0,1 + Double.Epsilon);
```

Seems like that would work, doesn't it? 1 + Double.Epsilon should be the next biggest number after 1 when working with doubles, right? This is how you would solve the problem with ints.

Wellllllllllllllll.........

I suspect that this will not work correctly, since the underlying code will be generating a few bytes of randomness, and then doing some math tricks to fit it in the expected range. The short answer is that Logic that applies to ints doesn't quite work the same when working with floats.

Lets look, shall we? (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,e137873446fcef75)

```
  /*=====================================Next=====================================
  **Returns: A double [0..1)
  **Arguments: None
  **Exceptions: None
  ==============================================================================*/
  public virtual double NextDouble() {
    return Sample();
  }
```

What the hell is Sample()?

```
  /*====================================Sample====================================
  **Action: Return a new random number [0..1) and reSeed the Seed array.
  **Returns: A double [0..1)
  **Arguments: None
  **Exceptions: None
  ==============================================================================*/
  protected virtual double Sample() {
      //Including this division at the end gives us significantly improved
      //random number distribution.
      return (InternalSample()*(1.0/MBIG));
  }
```

Ok, starting to get somewhere. MBIG btw, is Int32.MaxValue(2147483647 or 2^31-1), making the division work out to:

```
InternalSample()*0.0000000004656612873077392578125;
```

Ok, what the hell is InternalSample()?

```
  private int InternalSample() {
      int retVal;
      int locINext = inext;
      int locINextp = inextp;

      if (++locINext >=56) locINext=1;
      if (++locINextp>= 56) locINextp = 1;
      
      retVal = SeedArray[locINext]-SeedArray[locINextp];

      if (retVal == MBIG) retVal--;          
      if (retVal<0) retVal+=MBIG;
      
      SeedArray[locINext]=retVal;

      inext = locINext;
      inextp = locINextp;
                
      return retVal;
  }
```

Well...that is something. But what is this SeedArray and inext crap all about?

```
  private int inext;
  private int inextp;
  private int[] SeedArray = new int[56];
```

So things start to fall together. Seed array is an array of ints that is used for generating values from. If you look at the init function def, you see that there is a whole lot of bit addition and trickery being done to randomize an array of 55 values with initial quasi-random values.

```
  public Random(int Seed) {
    int ii;
    int mj, mk;

    //Initialize our Seed array.
    //This algorithm comes from Numerical Recipes in C (2nd Ed.)
    int subtraction = (Seed == Int32.MinValue) ? Int32.MaxValue : Math.Abs(Seed);
    mj = MSEED - subtraction;
    SeedArray[55]=mj;
    mk=1;
    for (int i=1; i<55; i++) {  //Apparently the range [1..55] is special (All hail Knuth!) and so we're skipping over the 0th position.
      ii = (21*i)%55;
      SeedArray[ii]=mk;
      mk = mj - mk;
      if (mk<0) mk+=MBIG;
      mj=SeedArray[ii];
    }
    for (int k=1; k<5; k++) {
      for (int i=1; i<56; i++) {
    SeedArray[i] -= SeedArray[1+(i+30)%55];
    if (SeedArray[i]<0) SeedArray[i]+=MBIG;
      }
    }
    inext=0;
    inextp = 21;
    Seed = 1;
  }
```

Ok, going back to InternalSample(), we can now see that random doubles are generated by taking the difference  of two scrambled up 32 bit ints, clamping the result into the range of 0 to 2147483647 - 1 and then multiplying the result by 1/2147483647. More trickery is done to scramble up the list of seed values as it uses values, but that is essentially it.

(It is interesting to note that the chance of getting any number in the range is roughly 1/r EXCEPT for 2^31-2, which is 2 * (1/r)! So if you think some dumbass coder is using RandNext() to generate numbers on a video poker machine, you should always bet on 2^32-2! This is one reason why we don't use Random for anything important...)

so, if the output of InternalSample() is 0 we multiply that by 0.0000000004656612873077392578125 and get 0, the bottom end of our range. if we get 2147483646, we end up with 0.9999999995343387126922607421875, so the claim that NextDouble produces a result of [0,1) is...sort of right? It would be more accurate to say it is int he range of [0,0.9999999995343387126922607421875].

My suggested above solution would fall on its face, since double.Epsilon = 4.94065645841247E-324, which is WAY smaller than 0.0000000004656612873077392578125 (the amount you would add to our above result to get 1).

Ironically, if it were not for the subtraction of one in the InternalSample() method:

```
if (retVal == MBIG) retVal--;
```

we could get to 1 in the return values that come back. So either you copy all the code in the Random class and omit the retVal-- line, or multiply the NextDouble() output by something like 1.0000000004656612875245796924106 to slightly stretch the output to include 1 in the range. Actually testing that value gets us really close, but I don't know if the few hundred million tests I ran just didn't produce 2147483646 (quite likely) or there is a floating point error creeping into the equation. I suspect the former. Millions of test are unlikely to yield a result that has 1 in 2 billion odds.

```
// Just try to explain where you got this number during the code review...
NextRandomRange(0,1.0000000004656612875245796924106);
```

**TLDR?**

Inclusive ranges with random doubles is tricky.

But if you are still with me, or you just hopped down here because you read the note at the top, here is a really simple solution that will work and it won't require you have a doctorate in discrete floating point math.

**The HACK**

If it is terribly difficult to generate a floating point number between {0,1}, lets just generate an int and convert it.

```
float fauxFloat = random.Next(0,11)/10;
```

Oooh, sneaky. Now, this wont give you much precision, so we can improve upon this by simply adding more:

```
public double RandomUnitInterval()
{
    var_Random = new Random();
    int precision = 1000000000;
    return (random.Next(0, precision + 1)) / ((double)precision);
}
```

If you set the precision to 10, and loop it, you will see that we land on both 0 and 1 occasionally. Mission accomplished. This example method gets you about 9 digits of precision past the decimal, so it should be pretty solid for most applications.

And that is how you can get a random number between {0,1} *inclusive*!

Answer (score 11):

You could, but you should do it this way:

```
double test = random.NextDouble();
```

If you wanted to get random integer ( 0 or 1), you should set upper bound to 2, because it is **exclusive**

```
int test = random.Next(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting zero because `Random.Next(a,b)` returns number in range [a, b), which is greater than or equal to a, and less than b.

If you want to get one of the {0, 1}, you should use:

```
var random = new Random();
var test = random.Next(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you asked for a number less than `1`.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4) says:

> **Return Value**
>   A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to minValue and less than maxValue; that is, the range of return values
>   includes minValue but not maxValue. If minValue equals maxValue,
>   minValue is returned.

Answer (score -1):

Rewrite the code like this if you are targeting 0.0 to 1.0

```
Random random = new Random();

double test = random.NextDouble();

Console.WriteLine(test);

Console.ReadKey();
```