# Generating a random double in range of [-1,1] in C#

Tags: c#, random, double

I'm trying to generate a random double value that is between -1 and 1 and also includes both of them. Since there is the negative aspect I couldn't find any solution on internet.

Comment: Generating random double-precision numbers within an inclusive range is tricky: [How to generate a random double number in the inclusive (0,1) range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66680283/how-to-generate-a-random-double-number-in-the-inclusive-0-1-range) Mathematically there are infinite real numbers in any given range, so the probability of selecting specifically any one of them is zero.

Answer (score 2):

`Random.NextDouble` provides values between 0 and 1.
So just multiply by 2, then subtract one...

```
var betweenMinusOneAndOne = (new Random().NextDouble() * 2) -1;
```

Comment: `Random.NextDouble` produces values in the range of `[0, 1)` - meaning greater than or equal to zero and ***less than one***. The OP specifically wants `1` included. `Random.NextDouble` can't do that.

Comment: Having said that, though, the chances of getting a `1` for a random number generator that produces `double` precision values on `[0, 1]` is really really small, so for practical purposes `Random.NextDouble` does a good job.